# How to export users along with manager email address values only

Tags: google-apps-script

found a script that exports our domain users email addresses along with the manager(relation), however I just want the email value of the user and manager. This script returns the user email address but the relation is formated {type=manager, value=useremailaddress.com}

```
function getDomainUsersList() {

var users = [];
var options = {
domain: "",     
maxResults: 100,
orderBy: "email",
projection: 'full'  
}

do {
var response = AdminDirectory.Users.list(options);
response.users.forEach(function(user) {
users.push([user.primaryEmail, user.relations]);
});

if (response.nextPageToken) {
options.pageToken = response.nextPageToken;
}
} while (response.nextPageToken);

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Users");
sheet.getRange(1,1,users.length, users[0].length).setValues(users);
```

}

Comment: Modify your ```forEach``` inside ```getDomainUsersList``` to check if the ```type``` of the relation is ```manager```, and if so, push the ```value```(which is the manager's email address) to the ```users``` array.